# Automatic page breaks

Tags: page-breaking, theorems

I'm currently writing my bachelor thesis and I'm having problems with automatically placed page breaks. Is it possible to forbid page breaks for example after the first line of a proof or a theorem environment? Because that doesn't look nice.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is a minimal working example of the unwanted behaviour:

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper,
twoside = false,
headings=standardclasses,
toc=chapterentrywithdots,
toc=bibliography]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
  automark,
  autooneside=false 
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks % erlaubt mit \displaybreak Zeilenumbrueche in align
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[satz]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[satz]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[satz]{Definition}
\newtheorem{beispiel}[satz]{Beispiel}
\newtheorem{beispiele}[satz]{Beispiele}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{bemerkung}[satz]{Bemerkung}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.   

At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
\begin{satz}
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus.   
\end{satz}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I think one can see the problem best in the generated PDF. Is it possible to upload a PDF to stackexchange?

Comment: Please show us some short example code that reproduces the problem. If we have some code to start with, providing a solution is usually much easier!

Comment: I've added a minimal working example. I hope one can see the unwanted behaviour.

Comment: There are many approaches: One is deal with orphan/widow penalties, as samcarter's answer, but you can also also suggest where should be a page a break (`\pagebreak[3]`)  or force it  when the suggestion is ignored  (`\pagebreak[4`], `\newpage`, `\clearpage` )  or make some part of text unbreakable with a parbox, or a minipage, or use `\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}`.

Comment: ... or allow some glue between paragraphs. Just a `\parskip` of `0em plus 1em` in the preamble of the MWE avoid the problem.

Comment: I don't really unterstand what `\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}` and `\parskip` of `0em plus 1em` do. Could you please explain the commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `nowidow` package to prevent single lines, for example the following will get require at least three lines before the pagebreak.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrbook}

\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}[chapter]
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[defaultlines=3,all]{nowidow}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5] aliquyam 
\begin{satz}
\lipsum[2] 
\end{satz}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't tested it with the original document yet but as far as I see it works with the MWE.

Comment: @LauraC If the question includes a nice MWE answering becomes easy :)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I just had problems with generating a minimal working example because I didn't know how to get the blindtext in the right position. Finally I've just copied blindtext from a lorem ipsum generator^^